# Is this a Sunflower? Well over 10 ft tall

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]Huge stem but not the broad heart-shaped leaves like I have seen in pictures of sunflowers. Leaves look more like those of *Helianthus*. Stem is a good 6 inches around and smooth not hairy. The red branches are also throwing me off. No flower yet. [image]. This is an Elementary School garden in Clermont, (central) Florida. We planted sunflower seeds, which is why, when they began growing that is what I thought they were. After much research I couldn't find any pictures that look like these plants. I have tomatoes and pepper plants in the same raised bed and it gets misters every 12 hrs for 3 hrs. Full, hot, Florida sun. If they are not sunflowers nor vegetable, we didn't plant it on purpose.

[image]

Comment: The trunk's glabrous whereas in sunflowers it would be hairy. As to Identification - is it developing a flower head of any sort anywhere? That might help pin it down if you can post a photo of that.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this plant. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. Clear, closeup photos of a leaf from above could also be helpful. Such questions should also use the [species-identification tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: I've made a few (what I hope are) improvements to your post — please check and make sure I've not misstated anything. In particular, I'm not sure what the red lateral structures are — I think they are branches rather than petioles (leaf stalks), but please change that if I am incorrect. ——— Also, this looks like it might be a school garden — do you have any way of finding out if these were planted intentionally or whether they are "volunteers"?

Comment: Could be pokeweed, though I associate that with reddish stems. Can you please edit with photos of the leaf blade

Comment: Pokeweed is a good guess. Whatever it is, it's definitely not a sunflower. Did you plant a maximillian sunflower by accident? Doesn't strongly resemble that, either, though.